# VHDL 3 bit adder. Error in declaration of the entity

Tags: vhdl

I am very new to VHDL and I have a piece of code where I just can't figure out the error. The message is:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at 3badder.vhd(6) near text "3";  expecting an identifier
```

My code:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity 3badder is
      port( a : in std_logic;
        b : in std_logic;
        c : in std_logic;
        sum : out std_logic;
        carry : out std_logic);
    end 3badder;
```

Answer (score 3):

Names cannot begin with numbers, change the name from "3badder" to "badder3".

Edit:

Have a look a some VHDL reference. One I found after a quick search:

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/Synario%20VHDL%20Manual.pdf

> "In VHDL, names ... must begin with a letter..." (2-9)